# changing standalone function to linux application

Tags: c, xilinx

I cannot run the below given code when I am not in standalone environment. How do I change the function to be used independent of standalnone environment.

==================================================

```
Xil_ExceptionEnable();

#define Xil_ExceptionEnable() \
        Xil_ExceptionEnableMask(XIL_EXCEPTION_IRQ)

#define Xil_ExceptionEnableMask(Mask)   \
{                               \
    register u32 Reg __asm("cpsr"); \
    mtcpsr((Reg) & (~((Mask) & XIL_EXCEPTION_ALL))); \
}
```

Comment: You can't simply use bare-metal code in a hosted environment. You need to rewrite anything that uses privileged features. Disabling interrupts will cause a lot of issues for Linux, so you're not allowed to do that from a user application.

Comment: Disabling interrupt does cause errors.

Comment: How do I chnage this below line in c, could you please help.

Comment: #define mtcpsr(v) __asm__ __volatile__(\
     "msr cpsr,%0\n"\
     : : "r" (v)\
   )

Comment: when asking a question about a run time problem.  As this question is doing, please post a [mcve] so we can help you.  As it is, the posted string of macros isn't even a function.